# Error installing torchvision (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to install torchvision by writing
`pip3 install torchvision`
but I get the following message

```
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from torchvision) (7.2.0)
Collecting torch==1.6.0 (from torchvision)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0 (from torchvision) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 0.3.0.post4, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.1.0.post2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.0.post2, 1.3.1, 1.4.0)
No matching distribution found for torch==1.6.0 (from torchvision)
```

I currently have torch==1.4.0 installed but it is apparently not sufficient to install torchvision. When I tried the code `pip3 install torch==1.6.0`
I got the following error

```
Collecting torch==1.6.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 0.3.0.post4, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.1.0.post2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.0.post2, 1.3.1, 1.4.0)
No matching distribution found for torch==1.6.0
```

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `pip3 install --upgrade torch` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. So I had torch==1.4.0 installed as this is the latest version acknowledged on my laptop, but for some reason when I tried to install torchvision, it immediately got to the latest version (0.7.0). I found on the pytorch website that torch==1.4.0 is associated to torchvision==0.5.0. So I ran the code `pip3 install torch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0` to get torchvision==0.7.0 uninstalled and install 0.5.0. Now it is working fine. Hope this explanation helps

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://pytorch.org/

And specify your platform. So far this is the best way to install what you need. For Windows it may be like this:

```
pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Search for the carrots:

[image]